# How to get a dynamic ListBox ItemTemplate to stretch horizontally the full width of the ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a normal listbox with a custom template to show the items. What I cannot manage is to stretch the template horizontally over the full widtg of the list box.

My problem is, that all of the elements in the main window are put dynamically, and they resize along with the window size changed method. I've searched through the net and the idea was to put HorizontalAligment="Stretch". This I tried, everywhere possible, with no significant success.

my xaml code goes like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LiveGames.Dealer.UsersList"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Background="Transparent">
<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" >
     <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="PlayerTemplate">
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" >
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.0" x:Name="gradientOne_Name" Color="Red" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" x:Name="gradientTwo_Name" Color="DarkRed" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions x:Uid="5">
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Name="RowH" Height="50"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!--  <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Player: " FontSize="18" />-->
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ID}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Canvas>
            <ListBox Name="userList" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PlayerTemplate}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Does anybody have any idea how to do this, maybe even in the code behind?

M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and solved it with the following Xaml (apply to the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle)

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

Also, you should be aware that by placing your ListBox inside a canvas, it won't stretch to fit its parent. It will be sized at whatever size you set the ListBox as Canvases' don't perform layout on their children.

Comment: Unfortuantelly this doesn't work for me. I tried to put the listBox out of the canvas but this doesnt help it either.

Comment: @user1448231 if you don't have it already, I strongly suggest you download Snoop for WPF at snoopwpf.codeplex.com. Using this you can visually debug your visual tree and find out which elements have which properties set (Filter by HorizontalAlign). You may find a binding is not setting the horizontal alignment properly, or another element requires horizontal alignment. Best regards,